# Search form on same line as navigation (array) php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm working in wordpress and would like to have the search form live on the same line as my navigation bar.  If the navigation was a div I think I'd know how to handle but the theme I'm working in is handling the nav as an array.  This line of code is what lives in my header.php file for the nav:

```
<?php
  wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'top', 
        'name' => 'top', 
        'container' => 'nav', 
        'container_id' => 'main-nav', 
        'menu_id' => 'top')
    );
?>
```

This is the code for the search form:

```
<div id="search"><?php get_search_form(); ?></div>
```

I think I would also know how to adjust the css if there were any issues, but any thoughts on how to combine this array with a div? It might be something simple but I'm still learning...thanks!

In response to the comment....
Here is the section's generated html:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="containerInner">
<header id="header">
<div class="logo">
<a href=""><img src="" /></a></div> 
<div id="search">
<form action="https://beta.harvest-express.com/" id="searchform" method="get"> 
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search for products" />
<input type="submit" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple" id="searchsubmit" value="Go" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" /></form></div> 
<div class="clear"></div>
<nav id="main-nav" class="menu-main-navigation-container"><ul id="top" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-10962" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-10717 current_page_item menu-item-10962"><a href="https://beta.harvest-express.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10956" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10956"><a href="https://beta.harvest-express.com/who-we-are/">Who we are</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10954" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10954"><a href="https://beta.harvest-express.com/how-this-works/">How This Works</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10953" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10953"><a href="https://beta.harvest-express.com/delivery/">Delivery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10955" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10955"><a href="https://beta.harvest-express.com/membership/">Membership</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10961" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10961"><a href="https://beta.harvest-express.com/contact-us-4/">Contact Us</a></li>
```

```
        </header>
```

And here is the relevant css for the search form and navigation:

```
.menu{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
padding:0 ;
margin-top: 10px;
background: url(images/line2.png) repeat-x bottom;
```

}

```
/* level 0
-------------------------------------------------------------- */


.menu > ul > li:first-child,
#main-nav > ul > li:first-child {
    margin-left:40px;
}
.menu > ul > li:last-child,
#main-nav > ul > li:last-child {
    margin-right:20px;
}

.menu > ul > li,
#main-nav > ul > li {
    padding: 3px 1px;
    margin-left:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.menu > ul > li .sf-sub-indicator,
#main-nav > ul > li .sf-sub-indicator {
    display: none;
}
.menu > ul > li.clearence,
#main-nav > ul > li.clearence {
    float:right;
}


.menu > ul > li.current_page_item,
#main-nav > ul > li.current_page_item ,
.menu > ul > li:hover,
#main-nav > ul > li:hover {
    padding: 2px 0px;
    border:1px solid #acacac;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    background: white;
}
#search {
float:right;
width:235px;
text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 0;
```

}

```
#search input[type="text"] {
    width:190px;
    color:#828282;
    font-size:11px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#search input[type="submit"] {
    color: #818181;
}
#search .button {
    margin-left:-30px;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    background: none;
}
#search .button span {
    color:#828282;
    background: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like a html / css question. Can you post the generated html and css of that section?

Comment: @jeroen I just posted the html and css. Any help you could offer would be awesome. thx

Answer (score 0):

You could start with:

```
#search, #main-nav {
  float: right;
}
#search + .clear {
  clear: none;
}
```

But if you can remove the `<div class="clear"></div>` between the two elements, you don't need the second rule.

Comment: hmm that just shifted (and scrunched) the entire menu bar to the right (along with the background image which is a line), not the individual list items

Comment: @JenileBrooks I took it from your post that you would be able to change the css, I think you just need to experiment (using inline-block, etc.). Hard to tell from here without having a complete overview and a page to test with.